# poor performance on mysql query on a VIEW. How to create index?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to run like 100 seperate queries that look like this

```
    SELECT SUM(worked_hours) as work_done, selected_date 
    from my_report_workbydate WHERE userid = ? and tid = ? 
    AND selected_date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY selected_date
```

looks like this

[image]

the data is created like this

```
create view my_report_workbydate as SELECT t.project as projectname, t.name as taskname, w.tid, t.username, w.userid, date(w.work_begin) as selected_date, ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, w.work_begin, w.work_end)/3600), 3) as worked_hours 
FROM my_worktime as w
LEFT JOIN my_task as t
ON w.userid = t.userid
AND t.tid = w.tid
GROUP BY w.userid, w.tid, w.work_begin order by selected_date desc;
```

a single query takes over 2 seconds on a slow server with a big database.
How can I speed the query up? I cannot create indexes in phpmyadmin on the view, there seems to be no option for it?

the indexes:

```
| my_task | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id 
| my_worktime | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | tid 
| my_worktime | 0 | PRIMARY | 2 | userid 
| my_worktime | 0 | PRIMARY | 3 | work_begin
```

my_worktime table EXPLAIN:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tid        | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| userid     | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| work_begin | datetime   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| work_end   | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

my_task explain:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| tid            | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| project        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| name           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| username       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| play_date      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| worked_time    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| estimated_time | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| created_on     | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| userid         | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

after using index on userid in the task table I could increase the speed by a huge factor.

The explain of a query now looks like this with a retrieval time of 0.08 seconds roughly. Is there any way to further speed it up?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the current indices on the two tables and the result of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @mrun i updated the post

Comment: That's more like `DESC`. I meant running the query with an `EXPLAIN` in front of it as in `EXPLAIN SELECT t.project as projectname,...`

Comment: I now added the explain to the post. I don't think one can further improve the latency?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with these ...

```
  CREATE INDEX  work_time_user ON work_time  (userid);
  CREATE INDEX  my_task_user ON my_task  (userid);
  CREATE INDEX  work_time_date ON work_time  (date(w.work_begin) );
```

Comment: that helped a lot, the problem was the userid on my_task. The retrieval time is now 0.2 seconds per query, so for 73 queries it is still 14 seconds though, which is a lot.

Comment: For better performance You can also try a redundant index,  adding to the index most selectived field the sequence of the other field involved in select  eg:  CREATE INDEX  my_task_user ON my_task  (userid, project, name, username); in this way all the information from this table are directly obtained form the index.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal RDBMS you would create a materialized view, but [MySQL doesn't support that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).  Instead of making a view, create the results as a table.  Index that table, then select from it instead.  This prevents needing to do a JOIN and GROUP BY for every single query you run against it.  Do keep in mind that your underlying tables may change so it may be required to rebuild your table on occasion.  (Again, this wouldn't be an issue if MySQL supported materialized views.)

Alternately, skip the view entirely.  The view is going to create all potential results, then filter it down to the records you're interested in.  By embedding your selection criteria in the query itself, it will filter before joining, not after.

Comment: I think creating extra tables is prone to housekeeping and a new set of bugs I really don't want to do.
Is there no way to use the view and having the benefits of filtering before joining?

Answer (score 0):

A single, composite, index will work better than any single index:

```
INDEX(userid, tid, selected_date)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql It explains to list the '=' columns first.

A `VIEW` won't help performance any.

If the data does not change after it is written, then consider building (and maintaining) a "Summary Table" of subtotals -- probably per user per day.  Then SUMming over that table would be much faster.